# mfp cordova create error

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobilefirst-windows

I am new in IBM mobilefirst and using 7.1 version in windows machine.

I am getting an error when trying to create cordova project from mobilefirst 7.1 CLI.

**Command** : mfp cordova create MfpCordovaDemo

**Error**: Implementation for this cordova subcommand has failed or not been provided: create.

I checked with mfp help command and got the below respond

```
CORDOVA CLIENT APP COMMANDS
 cordova create ................................. Creates a Cordova project
 cordova platform add|update|remove|list ......... Manages platforms in app
 cordova plugin add|update|remove|list|search ..... Manages Cordova plugins
 cordova preview|emulate|run ..... Runs App on Browser, Emulator, or Device
 cordova prepare .......... Prepares Cordova project resources before build
```

Any one has any idea regarding this`enter code here`?

Thanks,

Comment: what is your node and npm versions ?

Comment: Node : v8.4.0 , NPM : 5.3.0

Comment: Able to solve? I am having similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exactly error, but I'm manual and it work - Change resources.ts in /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/mfp_cordova_cmds/lib -> line 71

```
if (project && project2 && project3 && project4 && path.dirname(project) === path.dirname(project2) &&
```

if get error with MFP_CORDOVA_PATH not set -> vim ~/.bash_profile

```
export IBM_CLI_HOME=/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI
export MFP_CORDOVA_PATH=$IBM_CLI_HOME/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/cordovacmd/cordova
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$MFP_CORDOVA_PATH
```

-> source ~/.bash_profile to apply change, you can command 'echo $MFP_CORDOVA_PATH' to check

Try mfp cordova create again